# Passing a variable to a view from a different controller in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am building a simple voting application in Laravel 4 where candidates are being voted for. I have two entities Candidate and Vote with a one to many relationship. When someone clicks on a button, I get the id of the candidate and store it in the vote table with only one field of `candidate_id`. I have a `VoteController` function  called `votesuccess` that looks like this

```
$vote = new Vote;
$candidate_id =Input::get('name');
$candidate = Candidate::find($candidate_id);
$vote = $candidate->votes()->save($vote);
$count = DB::table('votes')->where('candidate_id','==','$candidate_id')->count();

Session::flash('message', 'Successfully Cast your vote!');
return Redirect::to('voteresults')->with('count',$count);
```

From the above I have another VoteController function called `voteresults` which I pass in all the candidates like so

```
$candidates = Candidate::all();
return View::make('votes.voteresults',['candidates'=>$candidates]);
```

Am storing the votes as rows and I want to count the votes by counting the rows hence this code

```
$count = DB::table('votes')->where('candidate_id','==','$candidate_id')->count();
```

am attempting to access all the candidate information plus the number of votes they have got from a view called `voteresults` which looks like this

```
<tbody>
@foreach($candidates as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{$value->avatar->url('thumb')}}"    alt="..."></td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->manifesto }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $count }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Am attempting  to pass the `$count` variable to the view so that I can capture the number of votes for a candidate. I don't know if it can be done this way or there is a better way to do it.When I try to run this I get `undefined variable count` Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get you correctly you want to pass two different things (candidates and votes) from your controller to your view?

Controller:

```
    $candidates = Candidate::all();
    $count = DB::table('votes')->where('candidate_id','=','$candidate_id')->count();
    return View::make('votes.voteresults')->with('candidates', $candidates)->with('count',$count);
```

View:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($candidates as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{$value->avatar->url('thumb')}}"    alt="..."></td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->manifesto }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $count }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

See this documentation:
[Views](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views)

Comment: Yes it works but the count variable returns zero for all candidates maybe there is something wrong with my query but how would I count the all the rows that have a particular `candidate_id`.

Comment: Ah ok, see jwalton512's updated answer. I believe that is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one issue you have is that within your where criteria for `$count` query you have your `$candidate_id` variable within single quotes.  I didn’t test, but try the code below.

```
$vote = new Vote;
$candidate_id =Input::get('name');
$candidate = Candidate::find($candidate_id);
$vote = $candidate->votes()->save($vote);

Session::flash('message', 'Successfully Cast your vote!');
return Redirect::to('voteresults');
```

Add a method to `Candidate` model similar to this:

```
 public function getTotalVotesAttribute()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('Vote')->whereCandidateId($this->id)->count();

 }
```

In your `VoteResults` controller:

```
$candidates = Candidate::all();
return View::make('votes.voteresults',['candidates'=>$candidates]);
```

In your `voteresults` view:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($candidates as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{$value->avatar->url('thumb')}}"    alt="..."></td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->manifesto }}</td>
        <td>
            {{ $value->total_votes }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: It works but it seems to show one number for all the candidates specifically the number for the candidate I have voted for. How do  I make it show individual votes for each of the candidates.